# AAPT2 missing in Android SDK

Tags: android, sdk, aapt2

I have lost the aapt2 file from android sdk.

can someone please tell me from where I can download the aapt2 file, as I am not able to build my application.

I tried finding an answer but it is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you lose it? There are two options with two different solutions:

- **Possible problem**: You (or another program) deleted AAPT2 manually.

  - **Solution**: Delete the whole `build-tools/<version with missing aapt2>` folder, then use the SDK Manager to re-download the removed build tools.
- **Possible problem**: You're using Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.0-alpha11 or newer which uses AAPT2 from maven and you're getting errors saying that AAPT2 was not found.

  - **Solution**: You need to make sure you have `repositories { google() }` under both `buildscript` and `allprojects` in your main build.gradle file.

Comment: Adding google() under allprojects works for me, it was missing. Thanks for that answer.